# File mode on MacOSX

Tags: files, permissions, osx

I'm familiar with the 3 file mode 'bits' defining user, group, and other permissions as well as the setuid/setgid/sticky 'bit', but when I `stat` the root level directories on my MacOSX laptop I see 1 to 2 extra fields. What are these?

```
 [onlyanegg@macosx ~]$ stat -f '%p %N' /*
 40775 /Applications
 40755 /Library
 40755 /Network
 40755 /System
 40755 /Users
 41777 /Volumes
 40755 /bin
 41775 /cores
 40555 /dev
120755 /etc
 40555 /home
100644 /installer.failurerequests
 40555 /mnt
 40555 /net
 40775 /opt
 40755 /private
 40755 /sbin
120755 /tmp
 40755 /usr
120755 /var
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`stat(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html) specifies that `%p` requests

> File type and permissions.

(look for "datum" in the linked page). The value displayed is all of `st_mode` (see [`stat(2)`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/stat.2.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/2/stat):

> ```
>  #define S_IFMT 0170000           /* type of file */
>  #define        S_IFIFO  0010000  /* named pipe (fifo) */
>  #define        S_IFCHR  0020000  /* character special */
>  #define        S_IFDIR  0040000  /* directory */
>  #define        S_IFBLK  0060000  /* block special */
>  #define        S_IFREG  0100000  /* regular */
>  #define        S_IFLNK  0120000  /* symbolic link */
>  #define        S_IFSOCK 0140000  /* socket */
>  #define        S_IFWHT  0160000  /* whiteout */
>  #define S_ISUID 0004000  /* set user id on execution */
>  #define S_ISGID 0002000  /* set group id on execution */
>  #define S_ISVTX 0001000  /* save swapped text even after use */
>  #define S_IRUSR 0000400  /* read permission, owner */
>  #define S_IWUSR 0000200  /* write permission, owner */
>  #define S_IXUSR 0000100  /* execute/search permission, owner */
> ```

This explains the values you're getting:

- values starting with 4 are directories (`/Applications`, `/Library`...)
- values starting with 12 are symbolic links (`/etc`, `/tmp`, `/var`)
- values starting with 10 are regular files (`/installer.failurerequests`)